# Generating encrypted passwords in mysql, to populate a django database

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django, encryption

This is a problem that I already have a passable answer to - so I'm posting here to see if anyone can improve it.

I'm migrating customer data from an old bespoke system (mysql database with cleartext passwords!!) to django. The data migration is to be accomplished solely with a set of sql scripts which can be run against both databases (moving and transforming data from the old database to the new). The process needs to be repeatable, predictable and potentially able to run unattended.

I need to take existing passwords, encrypt and store them in a format which is acceptable to Django (see details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/passwords/#auth-password-storage)). Ideally I would use django's preferred PBKDF2 hasher to do this, but that is hard since I cannot easily simulate the password stretching/multiple iterations that PBKDF2 does.

My workaround for now is to salt and encrypt the plaintext passwords using SHA1, and store them in Django. Then, the first time the customer logs in, Django automatically upgrades the password encryption to PBKDF2.

I wanted to use SHA2/SHA256 for this, but Django doesn't support this without PBKDF2, at least not unless I write my own password hashing backend and add it in django settings.py - which seems like a lot of effort.

Thus, I've arrived at the following in my migration sql script (simplified for clarity):

```
insert into auth_user(username,password)

SELECT username
    , CONCAT(
    'sha1$',
    @salt := SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 12),
    '$', SHA1(CONCAT(@salt,password))
    )  AS password
FROM
    old_user_table;
```

which outputs password strings like this:

```
sha1$a6acb1163c50$e7225b82280d66b4d8125cb7817b7854e98a5657
```

So far it works a treat - users can log in and the encryption is silently upgraded. The only downside is that we are using the relatively insecure SHA1 algorithm, at least until the user logs in once.

Can anyone improve on this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the plaintext passwords, so you could write a simple script that iterates through all of your users and authenticates them. Run this after your migration sql script and this will upgrade each user's password prior to you exposing it to real users, alleviating your concern about reduced security.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

for username, password in get_usernames_and_passwords():
    if authenticate(username=username, password=password) is None:
        print "Failed to authenticate user {!r}".format(username)
```

Comment: This is a good idea, although it doesn't fit with my requirement that everything can be completed in one pass with a set of sql scripts.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: I'm not privy to your environment, nor the reason for the restriction, however, something must be invoking mysql to run the sql migration script... that something could be a Python script that runs code similar to the above post-migration.

Comment: No restriction, I just don't want to have to add code to the django project and deal with deployments etc. Right now the migration process is pure sql, and thus easy to run independently of the dev team. I'll just be running it from my favourite mysql GUI (SQlyog).

Your solution is still a good one, it just doesn't quite fit with the way I want to do things. But I may well still implement it!